# Web worker as precise timer: inconsistent in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, timer, mobile-safari, web-worker

I'm using the following code in a `web worker` to schedule events to happen precisely 10ms apart.

This seems to work in all browsers except any iOS browser. (Desktop safari is fine.)

Worker `<script>` tag:

```
<script id="masterClock" type="javascript/worker">
  let onmessage = function (event) {
    let delay = 10; // milliseconds
    let time = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() < time + delay) { }; // waits 10ms increments in all browsers except mobile Safari
    postMessage({data: []});
  };
</script>
```

Main `<script>` tag (simplified):

```
let blob = new Blob([document.querySelector("#FastTimer").textContent]);
let blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let worker = new Worker(blobURL);

worker.addEventListener("message", receivedWorkerMessage);

// simplified example of interacting with the timer
function receivedWorkerMessage(event) {
    worker.postMessage(userInteractionData);
    doNextStepOfWork(); 
    counter++;  
}
```

Any suggestions/explanations appreciated!

Notes:

- I tried using a `setTimeout` based timer, but it was much too imprecise, and didn't help with iOS at all.
- I tried an alternative timer based on `requestAnimationFrame`, but it was also inconsistent in iOS.
- I've considered using `AudioContext`, but I wouldn't want to pre-schedule all the events, because the user interacts with them as they go; but maybe it could serve as the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an iOS device is likely to have power management features that can throttle or deprioritize JavaScript execution in the background or when the screen is off (as illustrated in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/49ieb6/safari_deprioritizing_javascript_and_affecting_a/)), you might need to consider another background task mechanism.

Try a [Web API Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) which would call your javascript loop:

```html
<script>
  const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

  worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    // Handle the message from the worker
    console.log('Message received from worker:', event.data);
  };
</script>
```

And your script:

```js
let delay = 10; // milliseconds

function timer() {
  let startTime = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < startTime + delay) {}
  postMessage({data: []});
  setTimeout(timer, delay);
}

timer();
```

---

But if the issue persists, then yes, an Audio worker is more precise. Since you need to keep the interaction going, consider a [Audio Worklet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorklet), which is used to supply custom audio processing scripts that execute *in a separate thread* to provide very low latency audio processing.

As the [documentation suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor#processing_audio), you would need to:

1. Extend the `AudioWorkletProcessor` class (see "[Deriving classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor#deriving_classes)" section) and supply your own [`process()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process) method in it;
2. Register the processor using [`AudioWorkletGlobalScope.registerProcessor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletGlobalScope/registerProcessor) method;
3. Load the file using [`addModule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule) method on your audio context's [`audioWorklet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/audioWorklet) property;
4. Create an AudioWorkletNode based on the processor. The processor will be instantiated internally by the [`AudioWorkletNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode) constructor.

Meaning create a `audio-worklet-processor.js`:

```js
class TimerProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  static get parameterDescriptors() {
    return [{ name: 'delay', defaultValue: 10 }];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.timer = 0;
  }

  process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    const delay = parameters.delay[0] || 10;
    this.timer += 128 / sampleRate * 1000; // 128 is the default buffer size

    if (this.timer >= delay) {
      this.timer -= delay;
      this.port.postMessage({ data: [] });
    }

    return true; // Keep the processor alive
  }
}

registerProcessor('timer-processor', TimerProcessor);
```

You can register it from your `worker.js`:

```js
(async () => {
  // Load the audio worklet processor
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('audio-worklet-processor.js');

  // Create the audio worklet node and connect it to the destination
  const timerNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'timer-processor');
  timerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  // Set up a message listener
  timerNode.port.onmessage = (event) => {
    // Handle the message from the audio worklet processor
    console.log('Message received from audio worklet processor:', event.data);
  };
})();
```

And call your worker:

```html
<script>
  const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

  worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    // Handle the message from the worker
    console.log('Message received from worker:', event.data);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I look forward to trying the audio worklet, and I appreciate the detailed answer. In the meanwhile, I don't understand how your top example differs from my own, which is also a web worker.  In my main script, I am calling the worker by `new Worker(blobUrl)` and I am getting the blobUrl as the `textcontent` of the `<script id="FastTimer">`  and the worker is simply in a different script tag within the main body of the HTML.  In yours, it's an external file.  Is that the only difference, or is there an implementation subtlety that I am missing?

Comment: @ultraGentle "In my main script, I am calling the worker by new `Worker(blobUrl)`": I see. This was not clear reading your original question, which is why I detailed that option first.

Answer (score 1):

This construct

```
while (Date.now() < startTime + delay) { }
```

is not very nice to the computer/device. It's the equivalent of flooring your accelerator and brake pedal at once. You are forcing one cpu to work 100% until you have 'paused' for a number of milliseconds. Why?

Instead just use a setTimeout, or setInterval or create your own async sleep function:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

That you can call like this inside any *async* function:

```
await sleep(milliseconds)
```

Or, I asked myself, am I missing something here: Is this waste of CPU power a more exact timer? So I made som test comparing calling the while loop and the *await sleep* with 10 ms as a delay and then checking the delay with **performance.now**. And both seems as exact/inexact - clocking in between 9.5-10.5 ms on my computer. So why use a blocking while-loop (I know it's in a worker so it's not blocking the main thread)? It's a waste of CPU cycles/battery power...

Comment: That's a good point. My main issue is consistency on iOS, however (it is not even close to 10 ms), and `setTimeout` 
did not solve that.  If anything, it seemed even more inconsistent.  I haven't tried an asynchronous version though, so I'll give it a shot too.